# c# Multipart Form Data Encoding

Tags: c#, https, multipartform-data

I'm working on a C# application that submits some small files to a device via multipart form data.  I've been unable to get the device to actually accept the data that I'm sending it and I have a feeling that it has to do with the actual encoding of the file as it's being transmitted somehow, but I'm not entirely sure.  It returns a 200/OK, as a valid POST, but doesn't like the payload.

I've been using Chrome Dev Tools for the devices web interface to match as closely as possible.  One thing I've noticed is that Dev Tools doesn't show me the actual payload, just the following as if it can't display it:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryWwZOi6WAr7yb3yRE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="[Redacted]"; filename="[AlsoRedacted]"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryWwZOi6WAr7yb3yRE--
```

Alternatively, the MessageBox I've been using to help debug seem to have no issue displaying it.

The relevant portions of the code are below and would appreciate any suggestions.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (MultipartFormDataContent Content = new MultipartFormDataContent(String.Format("----------{0:N}", Guid.NewGuid())))
        {
            StreamContent ContentStream = new StreamContent(fs);
            Content.Add(ContentStream, "filename", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Filename));
            ContentStream.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name = "UploadEdid";
            ContentStream.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileNameStar = null;
            ContentStream.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");


            String ContentString = Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ContentString, ContentString.Length.ToString());

            using (HttpResponseMessage Response = await HttpClient.PostAsync(RequestUri, Content))
            {
                if (Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    HttpLoggedIn = true;
                    string ResponseString = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    ParseHttpResponse(ResponseString);
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpLoggedIn = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 'It returns a 200/OK, as a valid POST, but doesn't like the payload', what makes you think that? Can you share a bit more information regarding the service you're attempting to communicate with? Is this something under your control ?

Comment: @Hintham It returns a JSON object telling me that the value is out of range, instead of the success object I get when using Chrome.

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler to intercept the chrome request and your request so you can compare them to see what's different?